# How to use diffusers StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline with "Inpainting conditioning mask strength 0-1" and an inpainting.ckpt model?

Tags: diffusion-models

I'm working on a project & want to change the art style of images but keep them close to their original form.

[image]

As shown in the image, this can be done using https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui (manually), but I want to do this with diffusers pipeline from https://huggingface.co/.

I am using this inpainting model https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-inpainting

1. I have tried StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline with above inpainting model:

```
pipeline = StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "runwayml/stable-diffusion-inpainting",            
    use_auth_token=HF_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    safety_checker=None,
    requires_safety_checker=False,
    revision="fp16",
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
).to("cuda")
result = pipeline(
    prompt="a woman making a stop sign with her hand, instagram contest winner",
    negative_prompt="bad drawing, extra limbs, low resolution, deformed, extra fingers",
    image=image,
    strength=1,
    num_inference_steps=20,
    num_images_per_prompt=1,
    guidance_scale=7,
    generator=torch.Generator(device="cuda").manual_seed(1)
)
```

And this throws:
[image]

2. When using StableDiffusionInpaintingPipeline with above model, it works without errors but requires me to send a mask. I tried with many different masks with no good results and I do not think that AUTOMATIC111 is doing it with inpainting.

How can I use the inpainting model with StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline to get the same results as in the web UI and what is "inpainting conditioning mask strength"? In case that functionality is not there with the pipeline, I have seen other people making their own custom pipelines. I will try that if someone can point me in the right direction.